# Difference between HttpContext.Current vs HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Context

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

What is the difference between :

```
HttpContext.Current
```

and

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Context
```

I have been told to use:

```
Dim context As HttpContext = HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Context
If Not IsNothing(context) Then 
    'do stuff with context
End If
```

But I am getting Null reference exceptions when trying to access ApplicationInstance.Context in the Application_EndRequest event.

**Which one should I be using?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The properties both return the current context of the Request. As `HttpContext.Current` is shorter, you should rather use this. Also, when checking against null/Nothing, the error you experience is clear:

If `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.Context` is null/Nothing, `HttpContext.Current` is null/Nothing. So the only working way to check the context against null/Nothing is:

```
If HttpContext.Current IsNot Nothing Then 
    ' ...
End If
```